# Strict mode not working

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have set strict to false in my database connection settings as follows:

```
   'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null
        ],
```

But I am still getting the GROUP BY ALL error message when trying to chain groupBy in an Eloquent query.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'spinal.exercise_programs.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `exercise_programs` where `client_id` = 1 group by `exercise_id`)
```

Need to use groupBy in this scenario:

```
$exercises = ExerciseProgram::where('client_id', '=', $client)->groupBy('exercise_id')->get();
```

Comment: try `php artisan config:clear`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear the `config` cache after you change any configuration in Laravel.

```
$ php artisan config:clear
```